# determining a implicit curve is simple or not

Tags: differential-geometry

First I know the definition of a simple curve, i.e., curve $p: I \rightarrow X$ is injective.

Now I want to know for given implicit curve $F(x,y)=0$ is a simple regular closed curve or not.

I can check regularity by finding critical values via $\nabla F=0$

But how about its simpleness? Before manipulating and massage into $(x,y)$ in the form of sin and cos, is there any other ways to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, a simple curve is a curve that doesn't cross itself.
How can we check if it's crossing itself? We have to look for "critical points", those points is which $\nabla F=0$. So, knowing that your curve is regular gives you automatically that your curve is simple.

How to check if your curve is closed: let $I=(\alpha , \beta)$, your curve is closed  if $p(\alpha)=p(\beta)$